# Race OOP structure

Tags: rpg, architecture

I am on a point that is totaly making troubles to me.
In my "Test Program" I have a Character. This character have some stuffs (hp mp, weapon, attackPoint, armor, ...) but also a Race, that can be 4 coices (Gnome, Elf, Human, Ogre).
So I was thinking to make 5classes : Race, Human, Elf, Ogre, Gnome. Thing is I don't know if this is a good idea... I though that Elf, Gnome human and ogre could be inherited from Race... What do you think about it ?

Character.h :

```
class Character
{
public:
   Character(int id);
   void display() const;
private:
   Gnome *gnome;
   Elf *elf;
   Ogre *ogre;
   int m_id;
};
```

Character.cpp :

```
Character::Character(int id) : m_id(id)
{
   if(m_id == 1)
      gnome = new Gnome();
   else if (m_id == 2)
      elf = new Elf();
   else if (m_id == 3)
      ogre = new Ogre();
}
```

Comment: Per the [help], questions asking "what do you think?" are generally too broad and discussion oriented to be considered on-topic here. What is the specific problem you are having with this implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on how the race affects the character.

**1)** Do you just want to save the type, e.g. when checking if the user is an Elf to receive bonus damage when wielding an Elvish Blade?

Then you might just go with an enum:

```
enum Race {
  Elf = 0,
  Ogre,
  Gnome,
  Human
};
```

**2)** If you want to include special behaviour and/or properties, you can go with a class system, where Elf is a special class of the abstract base class Race.

```
public class Character {
    private Race race;

    public Character(Race pRace)
    {
       race = pRace;
    }

    public void Walk() {
       race.Walk();
    }
}


public class Elf : Race {
    public override void Walk() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: The second choice is the best, so. Can you check the code edited above ?

Comment: You might want to take a look at Polymorphism: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29. You never (!) define three pointers for the same purpose. See my edited example above (code is in C#, as I am not very up-to-date in C/C++).

Comment: Ohh yep, true. I totaly forgot this, sorry for this, and thank you. I have now my answer.